# Why does an error occur when I modulus the value in array?

Tags: c++, arrays

may i know what exactly have gone wrong in this code? cause the output of the even number is not what i expected if i input the value in the comment

```
//int number[10]={0, 2, 5, 8, -2, 0, 6, 4, 3, 1};
int number[10], divided_number[10], total_odd_numbers, total_even_numbers, a;
for(int i=0;i<=9;i++){
    a=i+1;
    cout<<"Number "<<a<<": ";
    cin>>number[i];
    
}
for(int i =0; i<=9; i++){
    cout<<*(number+i)<<"  ";
}
cout<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<=9; i++){
    divided_number[i]=number[i]%2;
    if(divided_number[i]!=0){
        total_odd_numbers +=1;
    }
    else if (divided_number[i]==0){
        total_even_numbers++;
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<=9; i++){
    cout<<*(divided_number+i)<<"  ";
}
cout<<"\n Total odd number: "<<total_odd_numbers<<endl;
cout<<"\n Total even number: "<<total_even_numbers<<endl;
```

Comment: This is a small amount of code that you could debug yourself.  When you say it's not what you expect, _what_ output do you expect and what output are you actually getting?  Note that you also have a negative number and you're taking the modulo.  By the rules of that operator, the result can be negative.  Something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `total_odd_numbers` and `total_even_numbers` are not initialized before being accessed. This is called **undefined behavior**. In this case, the program will take whichever trash data is already in the memory assigned to those variables and just use it as-is (and so, of course, the output may or may not be correct, depends on what's in that memory at the time of assignment).

It should be noted that :

> Using an unitialized value is, by itself, not undefined behavior, but the value is simply indeterminate. Accessing this then is UB if the value happens to be a trap representation for the type. Unsigned types rarely have trap representations, so you would be relatively safe on that side.

Modified program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number[10]={0, 2, 5, 8, -2, 0, 6, 4, 3, 1};
    int divided_number[10], total_odd_numbers = 0, total_even_numbers = 0, a;

    for(int i =0; i<=9; i++){
        cout<<*(number+i)<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<=9; i++){
        divided_number[i]=number[i]%2;
        if(divided_number[i]!=0){
            total_odd_numbers +=1;
        }
        else if (divided_number[i]==0){
            total_even_numbers++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=9; i++){
        cout<<*(divided_number+i)<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<"\n Total odd number: "<<total_odd_numbers<<endl;
    cout<<"\n Total even number: "<<total_even_numbers<<endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0  2  5  8  -2  0  6  4  3  1
0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
 Total odd number: 3

 Total even number: 7
```

And, of course, the code could be cleaned up much further:

```
int number[10]={0, 2, 5, 8, -2, 0, 6, 4, 3, 1};
int odds = 0, evens = 0;

for(int i=0;i<=9; i++)
{
    int left = number[i] % 2; cout << left << " ";
    if (left != 0) {odds++;} else {evens++;}
}

cout<<"\nTotal odd number: "<<odds<<'\n'<<"Total even number: "<<evens;
```

Further reading:

- [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/)
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

And also:

- [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/)